# How do I define a security realm in a JavaEE Stack in Cloudbees?

Tags: jaas, cloudbees

I'm trying to run a simple web application in a JavaEE stack in CloudBees.  As part of this application, I define a security realm which is a DataSourceRealm

```
    <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ResmanRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/welcome.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/welcome.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I've written this to date using a local Glassfish3 server, in which I define the ResmanRealm against a JDBC resource.  In Glassfish3-config-speak, that ends up looking like this

```
        <auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm" name="ResmanRealm">
      <property name="jaas-context" value="jdbcRealm"></property>
      <property name="encoding" value="Hex"></property>
      <property name="password-column" value="password"></property>
      <property name="datasource-jndi" value="jdbc/ResManPool"></property>
      <property name="group-table" value="V_USER_ROLE"></property>
      <property name="user-table" value="USER"></property>
      <property name="group-name-column" value="role"></property>
      <property name="digest-algorithm" value="SHA-256"></property>
      <property name="user-name-column" value="name"></property>
    </auth-realm>
```

So, this all works locally.  I saw that in Cloudbees, there's a cloudbees xml file which the doco states is legacy, but looked like it had some form of support to for this.  What I cannot find is any examples of how to define a security realm as a Configuration Parameter.  It looks like if could be a resource (in CloudBees-speak), and you could define it as you bind a database to an application.  But, an example would be nice, as the existing resource examples (at least the ones I can find) are a bit general.

Also, the output log from my (currently unsuccessful) application startup don't show that DataSourceRealms are being loaded?

```
[#|2013-02-25T11:03:51.319+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service|#]

[#|2013-02-25T11:03:51.333+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.|#]

[#|2013-02-25T11:03:51.452+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2013-02-25T11:03:51.461+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2013-02-25T11:03:51.483+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.|#]

[#|2013-02-25T11:03:51.498+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.security.com.sun.enterprise.security|_ThreadID=12;_ThreadName=AutoDeployer;|SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully|#]
```

So, if anyone's had success with defining DataSourceRealms ina JavaEE stack in CloudBees, I'd appreciate any nudges in the right direction.  Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudBees now supports JaaS Authentication and Security Realms on the Glassfish3 and Glassfish4 stacks as documented here:

- Glassfish3:

  - Docs: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Glassfish3_JaaS_Authentication
  - Demo app: https://github.com/CloudBees-community/glassfish-clickstart
- Glassfish4:

  - Docs: https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Glassfish4_JaaS_Authentication
  - Demo app: https://github.com/CloudBees-community/glassfish4-clickstart

Please not that **CloudBees security realms for Glassfish3 and Glassfish4 are exclusively based on JdbcRealms** which seems to be your need.

Comment: Very delayed response, but I just came back to this and got it working.   Very awesome!  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Container based authentication isn't available on CloudBees stacks, but the tomcat6 for legacy reasons. Preferred approach is to instrument application with a security framework (spring-security or any other)